# Confusion with StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, scjp

Why is StringBuilder gives me an updated string when i use append but not when i use subString. Following is an example :-

```
class Hello{

 public void doSomething(){

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("animals");
sb.append("s");
System.out.println("Original        = "+sb); // prints animals
sb.substring(sb.indexOf("a"), sb.indexOf("al"));
System.out.println(sb);// prints animals

}
}
```

Comment: Which part of documentation makes you think that `substring` should modify StringBuilder?

Answer (score 3):

`substring` doesn't change the state of the `StringBuilder`. It returns a String containing the requested substring. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring(int,%20int)) for more details.

I think what you were looking for is [`StringBuilder#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int))